# libgdx ShapeRenderer renders multiple times with moving camera

Tags: java, libgdx

I decided to use Libgdx `ShapeRenderer` for drawing polygons. I wanted to see how efficient this is and let the camera go through the x-axis while rendering, but something strange happened, see this picture:

[image: http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/2523/testfl.png]

On the right side, I didn't move the camera, but on the left I moved the camera via

```
camera.translate(0.1f, 0);
```

Here is my code:

```
public void setSize (int width, int height) {
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(30f * aspectRatio, 30f);
}
public void render() {
    camera.update();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);        
    shapeRenderer.identity();
    camera.translate(0.1f, 0);      
    shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    shapeRenderer.polygon(new float[] {0,0,5,5,5,2.5f, 10,12.5f, 10,0});                
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, but I think it doesn't delete the image below it.

Comment: Are you clearing the screen before you render?

Comment: thank you! when i changed my code, i delete that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call before you render:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```